# Positioning Text & Button on top of Video Header

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I tried looking this up, but I'm having a hard time relating others' code to my own, so I hope it is okay that I'm creating this post.

I've been stuck on this site I'm trying to create for my dad. I'm using a template right now, but will be building from the ground up, just trying to figure out the pieces.

kgshowroom.com/test

As you'll see, there is a looping video in the header of the home page (not ours — this site is not advertised to the public, so just needed an example to play with). However, before I put that in, the part just underneath that ("KG Showroom" + "You're on our site." + the "Hello!" button) was up at the top and centered on top of a photo of a kitchen.

When I put in the video, all of that got pushed down, below the div (my guess, at least). I want those items to sit back on top of the looping video. I don't want the video to be clickable, but I want the "Hello!" button to be clickable.

So I added the following to .header-video:

position: absolute;

z-index: -1;

When I add that code in the "Inspect Element" feature in Chrome, it shows the text and button overlaying (although not centered, as I hoped). However, when I try to upload the same code to the site, it's not showing up at all. Someone suggested that my @media queries might be overriding the code, but I'm not finding "@media" in my code anywhere.

Ideas?

Comment: So your question, since I don't see `.header-video` in your code anywhere, is why this style rule won't upload to your server?

Comment: You review these then post the code that is related to your issue: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ | https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Michael_B Hi, it's in style.css under /*********************************** New Code for Video Header **************/ And yes, that's my question. Or if it is uploading, is there something overriding it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Hi @vanburenx — I would post the code that's related to my issue, but I'm not sure what it is (and that's the issue! :). I posted the portion that I know of in the post, but it's as much as I know.

Comment: Your stylesheet in your code is `stylesheets/mainstyle.css`. Where is the `style.css` file you're referring to?

Comment: You reference this text in your question `"KG Showroom" + "You're on our site." + the "Hello!" button`. I understand it's not displaying and you're trying to get that fixed. But it's not even in your HTML code.

Comment: @Michael_B it should be http://kgshowroom.com/test/

Comment: LOL! you didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Oh my gosh @Michael_B! I'm sorry (wow)! That's the OLD site which is what the public is still directed to, and I'm trying to create a new site in the /test subdirectory. So sorry about that! But now the video is gone. Something funky is going on (and I promise, this is the first time I've made a mistake like that — everything was in order!). When I tried uploading the style.css again to make sure you could see it (just in case), it uploaded the original css file w/ the photo in it, not the one I modified to have the video; basically, that's what I want it to look like though (w looping vid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works.

Edit this code block in your stylesheet.

**ORIGINAL**

```
#header .inner
        {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 4em 0 0 0;
        }
```

**REVISED**

```
#header .inner
        {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            margin: 0;
            top: -210px;
         }
```

#### A note about `z-index`

Keep in mind that `z-index` controls the "stack level" of a positioned element (in your case `position: absolute`). This higher the `z-index` value, the higher the element is in the stack.

So when you specify a `z-index` value of -1 (like in your question), you're telling the box to stack underneath any other boxes with a higher value (such as 0). If you want something to always appear on top of everything else, give it a high `z-index` value such as 999.

I hope this helps. If you have any questions just leave a comment below.

**UPDATE**

To center the KG Showroom box add these rules to the `#header .inner` declaration block:

```
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

To remove the double lines, delete this code the HTML `div` container:

```
<hr>
::before
::after
</hr>
```

After you delete it, if you want to adjust spacing, simply use `padding` and `margin` properties.

Comment: with: `<div class="inner" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; top: -210px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">`

Comment: Oh, ok. I just said that the new code brought it to the middle which was awesome, but I changed top:  -210px to top: 0px  in the HTML and CSS because it was pushing it to the top (and centering it there). It is now centered in both directions (x,y axis relative to the video) but not sure if my fix is a bandaid fix or if it's proper coding?